# Convert Hexadecimal string to integer in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth application which is receiving data in Hexa format in this format 
"`01 0D 18 DA F1 10 03 41 0D 00`"

convert this into the decimal and display in my app.

I am using this kind of logic.

```
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(data1,16);
```

but i want to convert particluar byte like in the above example. I want to decode only "`03 41`" into decimal and display .
please help me out in this.

Comment: Split and take out the elements that you want, and then convert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is split the Hexa string and store it in an array like

```
String[] array=Hex.split("\\s+"); //using space
```

and then parse it like

```
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(array[1]+" "+array[2],16);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is split the String with `data1.split(" ")` and then get the piece(s) you need. After that, just run those through the `Integer.parseInt(input, 16)` method and that should be it I think.

For reference, [here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the javadoc on String.split()

Answer (score 1):

It's simply too big for an int (which is 4 bytes and signed).
The maximum value that a Java Integer can handle is 2147483657, or 2^31-1.
So You should use **long** and then cast it to **int**

Use

int myInt = (int)Long.parseLong(data1, 16);

hope this helps..!